# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while removing mysql completely from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dpkg, ubuntu-20.04

I want to uninstall mysql completely from ubuntu 20.04.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y`

But every time got errors.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I tried configuring dpkg `sudo dpkg --configure -a` , but again it says :

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0

Answer (score 4):

I had the same challenge in `xubuntu 20.04`. This is what worked for me after several attempts.
I hope it helps someone in future.

1. list all files associated with mysql-server

```
sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i mysql-server
```

2. Remove the different file groups.

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.*
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-core-8.0.*
```

3. Run

```
sudo apt update
```

Try reinstalling whatsoever you will trying to install.

Comment: This is definitely bad advice. As that might leave around cruft around. Manually removing files from the dpkg database should never be a first option, tried or offered, and less so in case the person doing it does not entirely know what might be the consequences. In this case dpkg helpfully provides what the correct solution is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, my experience with all the other suggestions proofed otherwise useless. My answer is based on what eventually ended up working for me. It was my last resort, and it worked. Sometimes the best solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your current issue. In order to completely get rid of your MySQL installation you could run the following:

Make sure MySQL is not running:

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
```

Then purge all of the MySQL packages:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

Then delete all of the MySQL files:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Finally clean all packages that are not needed:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to deal with such problem is to follow the instructions dpkg gives. One problem is that apt will refuse to act on such actions in those cases, so what you'd need to do is to `apt download` the required packages and reinstall them manually with `dpkg -i`.

After the packages have been reinstalled, then you can check whether the system is good again with `dpkg --audit`.